# Using ggplot to link points of interest in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, edges

I am trying to create a scatterplot, and then add lines between points in the scatterplot. I can get this to work using `plot` and `segments`, as shown below:

```
set.seed(10)
xvar = runif(10, 0, 1)
yvar = runif(10, 0, 1)

start = c(1, 1, 1, 9)
end = c(2, 4, 6, 10)

plot(xvar, yvar)
segments(xvar[start], yvar[start], xvar[end],yvar[end], col= 'blue')
```

I would like to achieve the same type of idea, but with using ggplot2. My reasoning for this is that I may want to add aesthetics to the plot, and ggplot2 allows this more than `plot`. I tried variants of:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) +
  geom_point(shape=20, size=1) +
  segments(xvar[start], yvar[start], xvar[end], xvar[end], col = 'blue')
```

But to no avail. Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use `geom_line` and to define groups (`gr`) for every segment:

```
dat <- data.frame(xvar = xvar, yvar = yvar)    
dat2 <- cbind(dat[c(start, end), ], gr = 1:length(start))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + geom_point(shape = 20, size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, group = gr), data = dat2)
```

[image]